# How to write a script to create and populate new spreadsheets from a master document?

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to create a pupil progress sheet for each of my pupils that is held in my gdrive and is owned by me (Teacher).This spreadsheet would use import range to pull test data from the 'Class sheet'. The pupil would be able to view their file but not make changes, or make a copy of the file so that they can make changes!).

This I can do manually but doing this for a class of 30 (let alone the 10 classes I have!) would be tedious in the extreme. I would imagine that a script might be able to automate much of this and I was wondering if there are any showstoppers in the list of requirements below before investigating further.

Is it possible to create a script that does the following from a MASTER SHEET (below):

```
A   B   C              D
1   ID  NAME    EMAIL
2   1   sample  sample@gmail.com
3   2   sample2 sample2@gmail.com
```

1) Run through the list above and create a duplicate of a separate template Google Sheets file for each person in Column C.

2) Rename the sheet to their name using column C

3) Populate a single cell (A1) within the new spreadsheets with their ID (Column B)

4) Share with the email (Column D) allowing VIEWING only and disabling copying the file etc.

Comment: Pretty sure if you can view it then you can create a copy by just appending /copy with the URL. It seems to be the case in my test. Everything else is possible though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a "Master" document, only readable and not editable by anyone else but you. That document can be accessible to all your students after you  share it with a "public link" to view (not to edit).

With the help of Google's SpreadSheet, you can create a file with different questions for instance, and run a script to generate different types of tests, but this might require a little of knowledge of Javascript. You can [learn how to make Google drive scripts from tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles).

For me, the creation of automatic named files for every student, and send emails automatically is not a great idea, but yes you can do it and there are [tutorials on how to send emails from a Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails#section1).

The best option is to just give a link to your students.
Preferably, after you create a sharing link from Google Drive, you should make the link as short as possible, by using a free service like the site [bit.ly](http://bit.ly) where any huge and hard to remember old link, can be shortened to something more easy to use like `bit.ly/TomTests_Oct2016`.

You can also consider to use [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/) if it fits your needs, since you are a teacher. This is definitely one good platform to evaluate students progress, with a lot of free content (if not everything).